# Как подключить отдельный скрипт из библиотеки?

Tags: javascript, scss

Устанавливаю [materializecss](http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html)

Если полностью устанавливаю js , то всё работает.

А если скачать Sass версию и там все js скрипты по-отдельности, устанавливаю то что нужно и почему-то не работает? Что не так?

Comment: а что пишет в консоль?

Comment: ничего не пишет, просто не работает.

Comment: что не работает? какая то ошибка есть? если ошибок в консоли нет, то необходим пример кода который у вас не работает, тут экстрасенсов нет.

Comment: Хотя есть одна TypeError: `$dragTarget.hammer is not a function`

Comment: Загрузил ещё jquery.hammer.js, всё равно не работает

Comment: Вы должны знать что и от чего зависит, иначе ошибок не оберёшься.